# PostgresSQL - keep the sequences of several tables connected after trigger

Tags: postgresql

I'm creating an offline naturalist input application. My database being very consequent, I decided to create a schema apart from my main database (I mainly need it to meet the constraints of offline data entry).
My idea is the following: use triggers to fill the tables of my schema consult from my schema data. The tables are the same from both sides. This works well with the following triggers.

However, I lose the link between my tables and I don't know how to solve this problem.
Here are the links :

```
Table : lieux, pk : id in serial 
    linked to 
Table : inventaire_mobile with the field : id_lieux in integer.

Table : inventaire_mobile, pk : idfiche in serial 
    linked to 
Table : citations with the field : idfiche in integer.
```

Could you please bring me some leads?

Best Regards,
Mathias

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION data.fk_lieu()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
INSERT INTO consult.lieux(type,nom,actif,geom,idobs,public,custom)
    VALUES(NEW.type,NEW.nom,NEW.actif,NEW.geom,NEW.idobs,NEW.public,NEW.custom);
RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;


CREATE TRIGGER nouveau_lieu
BEFORE INSERT ON data.lieux
FOR EACH ROW 
EXECUTE PROCEDURE data.fk_lieu();


-----------------
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION data.fk_inv()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
INSERT INTO consult.inventaire_mobile(date_deb,date_fin,idobs_saisie,id_lieux,geom,lieu_auto)
    VALUES(NEW.date_deb,NEW.date_fin,NEW.idobs_saisie,NEW.id_lieux,NEW.geom,NEW.lieu_auto);
RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;


CREATE TRIGGER nouveau_inv
BEFORE INSERT ON data.inventaire_mobile
FOR EACH ROW 
EXECUTE PROCEDURE data.fk_inv();


------------------------
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION data.fk_cit()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
INSERT INTO consult.citations(id,nombre,idfiche,idtaxo,mode_contact)
    VALUES(NEW.id,NEW.nombre,NEW.idfiche,NEW.idtaxo,NEW.mode_contact);
RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;


CREATE TRIGGER new_cit
BEFORE INSERT ON data.citations
FOR EACH ROW 
EXECUTE PROCEDURE data.fk_cit();
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'I lose the link between my tables'.

Comment: Where are the above triggers being run, on the offline device or when you connect? Also what does offline mean?

Comment: The trigger are just working online. 
What I mean is that the serial are not coherent when I "push" my data in the other schema. One record fill 3 tables. These 3 tables are well connected in the data schema. I loose the link between my entities when they arrive in my consult schema.
I thought about starting the sequence at the last number of my consult schema. But if something get upload on the consult schema that will broke my idea. Thanks for your help guys!

Comment: ps: for the software that I use offline, the relations must obligatorily relate to cardinalities 1 for the 1-n relations. So I can't create a different relationship field.